# Http post request inside a GPS Listener...initiated by a Service

Tags: android, eclipse, locationlistener

I'm doing an app in which a Service initiates a GPSListener which gets location updates in a regular interval of time.Upto this part its woking fine,and Im getting updates correctly.

I need to update this lat,long values to a server database,for which I use a http post request to a php script;which individually works fien.But when its called inside the LocationListener,Im getting the following error stacktrace.

How can I overcome this situation and make the post request?

```
> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at com.childtrack.service.SimpleService$mylocationlistener.postData(SimpleService.java:165)
at com.childtrack.service.SimpleService$mylocationlistener.onLocationChanged(SimpleService.java:101)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:237)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:170)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:186)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4899)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err(5560): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at com.childtrack.service.SimpleService$mylocationlistener.postData(SimpleService.java:165)
at com.childtrack.service.SimpleService$mylocationlistener.onLocationChanged(SimpleService.java:101)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:237)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:170)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:186)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4899)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing `network operation` on main(UI) thread. do use `asyntask` for network operation.
android does not allow to perform network operation on main thread. because it may freezes the `UI`.

whenever this exception occur **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException** its mean you have done something network operation on UI.

**Even though Service is intended for background processing they run in the main thread .**

A short quote from the documentation:

```
Caution: A services runs in the same process as the application in which 
it is declared and in the main thread of that application, by default. So, 
if your service performs intensive or blocking operations while the user 
interacts with an activity from the same application, the service will 
slow down activity performance. To avoid impacting application performance, 
you should start a new thread inside the service.
```

Comment: But @wqrahd ,Im having the request inside a Service...whethere that will also be treated as a UI thread???

Comment: i never used service but i think yes. thats why it is throwing exception.

Comment: i just read service also runs in main thread. i am updating my answer.

Comment: Yes @wqrahd...using an AsyncTask solved my problem...and hope this method is the most easiest to update GPS location to a server according to me...Kudos friends...